# Commenting on a POST using Facebook Graph api

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-comments

I am having a post id, and i want to comment on that post using c#. I am using the Facebook SDK 6.4.2. 
Now while using the graph explorer i am able to comment like

```
postid/comments?message=Commented using graph api explorer"
```

In c# I am doing as below

```
var client = new FacebookClient(accesstoken);
var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>
                    { 
                         { "message", "hi! this is my status message" },
                         { "place",postid}
                    };
client.Post("me/feed", parameters);
```

It is showing the error:(OAuthException - #1) An unknown error has occurred.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: The error message is (OAuthException - #1) An unknown error has occurred.

Comment: Thanks, I think for such things you need to use the OAuth token of your user to post a comment, otherwise everybody will be able to post comments for all users in FB. If it still doesn't work look at your Facebook App configuration, you can enable this.

Comment: I am trying to comment on a post on my page(I am the admin) i have the access token with full permissions

Comment: Ok, I never used the C# API but I guess you have to provide the OAuthToken and OAuhtSecret to your `var client`. That's why you get the OAuth exception. Is it an ASP.Net application>

Comment: Yes it is am ASP.NET application

Comment: Can you tell me how to get the OAuthToken and OAuthSecret

Comment: I created an answer with different steps to fix your problem

Answer (score 1):

Like the error message says, you need to use OAuth tokens to publish comments on Facebook.

**Obtaining tokens:**

For obtaining those tokens you need to [redirect your user to Facebook end get response tokens](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/).Once authenticated in Facebook your user will be redirected to your application and then you can store those tokens provided by Facebook in your database if you want.

**Authorization:**

I cannot find the documentation of your SDK, but according to the [JavaScript SDK documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/using-comments/) (section "Creating comments and replies"):

> Permissions
>
> This call must be made with publishing permission and a
> valid access_token. The token should be from a person or page that is
> allowed to comment on the parent object on Facebook. In order to
> create a comment as a Page, a page access token is required.

It says that your need both "publishing permission" and "publishing permission". For your SDK parameters name could be differents but the principle is the same.

**To summarize** you need the approval of the user (obtaining tokens) and post on his behalf (authorization).